# How to cancel 'seeking' state of Flex3 VideoDisplay class

Tags: apache-flex, video, flex3

I have a `VideoDisplay` instance playing some video. When I click on the video slider (also my component) the property `videoDisplay.playheadTime` is set and the `videoDisplay.state` goes from 'playing' into a 'seeking' state for a brief moment (the `videoDisplay` seeks for a new position and then plays the video again). Intended bevaiour.

But if I'm (or any random user) fast enough, I can set the `playheadTime` again while the player is still in 'seeking' state. When repeated several times every click is enqueued and the `videoDisplay` jump on every place of the video I have clicked(this is happening in an interval about 10-15 second after my last click). When I use live dragging the `videoDisplay`, overwhelmed by seekings, goes into 'error' state.

My question is - is there any way to cancel seeking state of the `VideoDisplay` class? For example player is in 'seeking' state, I set `playheadTime`, and the player forgets about last seeking and try to find the new place of the video.

I will downvote pointless answers like 'Use the Flex4 VideoPlayer class'!

Comment: can you please share the code for the video player??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way is wrap the video display in a component and manage the seek a little better yourself.  So if someone calls seek, make sure that the video is not currently seeking, if so, then wait till the current operation is complete before proceeding to the new one.  If the user tries to seek again, discard all currently pending operations and make the latest one the next operation.  Working on this exact problem right now.... Here's the code:

```
public function Seek(nSeconds:Number, bPlayAfter:Boolean):void
{ 
    trace("Player Seek: "+ nSeconds);
    var objSeekComand:VideoPlayerSeekCommand = new VideoPlayerSeekCommand(ucPlayer, nSeconds, bPlayAfter);
    ProcessCommand(objSeekComand);
}

protected function ProcessCommand(objCommand:ICommand):void
{
    if(_objCurrentCommand != null)
    {
        _objCurrentCommand.Abort();
    }

    _objCurrentCommand = objCommand
    objCommand.SignalCommandComplete.add(OnCommandComplete);
    objCommand.Execute();
}
```

Here's the Command

```
public class VideoPlayerSeekCommand extends CommandBase
    {
        private var _ucVideoDisplay:VideoDisplay;
        private var _nSeekPoint:Number;
        private var _bPlayAfterSeek:Boolean;
        private var _bIsExecuting:Boolean;

        public function VideoPlayerSeekCommand(ucVideoDisplay:VideoDisplay, nSeekPointInSeconds:Number, bPlayAfterSeek:Boolean,  fAutoAttachSignalHandler:Function = null)
        {
            _ucVideoDisplay = ucVideoDisplay;
            _nSeekPoint = nSeekPointInSeconds;
            _bPlayAfterSeek = bPlayAfterSeek;

            super(fAutoAttachSignalHandler);
        }

        override public function Execute():void
        {
            //First check if we are playing, and puase if needed
            _bIsExecuting = true;
            if(_ucVideoDisplay.playing == true)
            {
                _ucVideoDisplay.addEventListener(MediaPlayerStateChangeEvent.MEDIA_PLAYER_STATE_CHANGE, OnPlayerStateChangedFromPlay, false, 0, true);
                _ucVideoDisplay.pause();
            }
            else
            {
                DoSeek();
            }

        }

        protected function OnPlayerStateChangedFromPlay(event:MediaPlayerStateChangeEvent):void
        {
            _ucVideoDisplay.removeEventListener(MediaPlayerStateChangeEvent.MEDIA_PLAYER_STATE_CHANGE, OnPlayerStateChangedFromPlay);
            if(_bIsExecuting == true)
            {
                if(_ucVideoDisplay.playing == false)
                {
                    DoSeek();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Error("VideoPlayerSeekAndPlayCommand - OnPlayerStateChangedFromPlay error");
                }
            }
        }

        private function DoSeek():void
        {
            if(_bIsExecuting == true)
            {
                _ucVideoDisplay.seek(_nSeekPoint);
                CheckSeekComplete();
            }
        }

        private function CheckSeekComplete():void
        {
            if(_bIsExecuting == true)
            {
                if (Math.abs( _ucVideoDisplay.currentTime - _nSeekPoint) < 2)
                {
                    if(_bPlayAfterSeek == true)
                    {
                        _ucVideoDisplay.play();
                    }
                    DispatchAndDestroy();
                }
                else
                {
                    CoreUtils.CallLater(CheckSeekComplete, .07);
                }
            }
        }

        override public function Abort():void
        {
            _bIsExecuting = false;
            SignalCommandComplete.removeAll();
        }
    }
```

Im Using AS3 Signals here instead of events, and the CoreUtils.Call later you can use setInterval, or a Timer.  But the idea is to not call seek until the video is paused, and to keep track of when the seek is complete.

Comment: Sorry my example is so heavily abstracted, in the middle of working on a large video system....

Comment: 10x for the answer. This question is already 8 months old and I no longer have this problem(I don't even remember how I fixed it) but will accept and upvote your answer.